# How to get current time in java without Creating an Object each time?

Tags: java, calendar

I know there are a lot os posts about how to get the current time in java. But im planning to code a getAge Method in a Persona class. The problem is, I need to get the current time each time method is called. Let's say a billion clients execute getMethod(with miliseconds, perhaps seconds of difference), a billion of objects will be created for such a simple thing. The only thing I did was create a member static in Person, so Person will share the instace. But this doesnt prevent the object creation.

```
public class Person{
//Some Attributes
private static Calendar now;
private Calendar birthDate;

public short getAge(){
now = Calendar.getInstance();

return  (short) (( now.getTimeInMillis() - birthDate.getTimeInMillis())/ 31536000000L;
}}
```

If you know some library that have this implemented without the waste of such heap size. Please tell me.

Thanks.

Comment: Will you have a "billion clients" calling your service? Are you constrained to a 6-year old/embedded, single-core processor? Are you running with a heap-size of, like, 64mb? If these are true, you might want to look at this. If not, this is sub-optimization.

Comment: It's  good observation. I just want to optimize as much as I can do. there's no time constraint in this project.

Comment: Don't optimize for the sake of optimizing. Oftentimes, it leads to code that is harder to maintain and understand. It can also introduce other behavior that is unintended. If you look at anubhava's answer, for instance, introduces potential concurrency issues in a multithreaded environment that you now have to account for. Unless an optimization delivers real, measurable and significant improvments, it's not an optimization, it's just waste, technical debt and increased complexity.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can also create a Calendar instance once and keep calling:

```
calendar.setTimeInMillis ( System.currentTimeMillis() );
```

to set the current time in calendar instance and use that calendar object to do any date calculation.

Comment: Correct. I have to check this as the answer since this is more detailed. Votes for Keppil anyway.

Answer (score 9):

No need to create a `Calendar`, you can get a `long` from the static method

```
System.currentTimeMillis();
```

Comment: Not sure if I'm getting more lazy or just more stupid. That was great thanks!

Answer (score 0):

With the time stamp obtained through optimized means, what additional processing / overheads will be required to make the obtained time stamp meaningful?

http://joda-time.sourceforge.net

If you would like a library to work with date and time, go with Joda Time. I wouldn't bang on any work around.

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime();  // current time
```

I suggest that if performance is a key concern / limiting issue that you run tests to ensure that any work around that you accept achieves non-functional results that outweigh code readability.

Comment: Plus one because Joda will be the default in java 8. But still have the problem of the object innecesary creation.

Comment: Just going to be similar to Joda, JSR-310. You have to weigh the pro and cons. Object instantiation isn't a key issue in today's computing. Per say, it isn't a problem.

Comment: Chin Boon. If I could use Joda with JPA Eclipselink, without ask I would be using it.